# How to upgrade from psql 9.5 to 12 with short downtime and no corruption

Tags: postgresql, linux, ubuntu, postgresql-9.5, postgresql-12

We have two databases in two different servers with PostgreSQL 9.5

One database size is 800GB and the other is 1.8 TB.

What would be the most efficient and safe way of upgrading both clusters from version 9.5 to 12?

I have two backups of each DB:
A `pg_dumpall` file and a copy of the whole main data directory. So, any type of suggested test can be done with no fear.

Answer (score 0):

Fastest is to use pg_upgrade and be moderately lucky.

For a linked upgrade once you launch the new database there's no going back to the old one, but until then any errors will only abort the upgrade and you can revert to using the old database. After that going back would require restoring a dump.

If you have a lot of stored code you may find that some of it breaks. standard conforming strings is another thing to watch for if you weren't using it.